# Can we post information about the site on AskAboutProjects?

Tags: discussion, promotion

I've checked [AskAboutProjects](http://askaboutprojects.com/) and it seems every few days there are a couple of new questions there. Also from time to time people come by and answer questions. I think it would be a good idea to direct theme here.

Can we put there some big visual telling people about PM @ StackExchange and that we're now building this site up?

I know there's an old question regarding [StackExchange proposition](http://askaboutprojects.com/questions/2130/meta-vote-for-us-on-stackexchange) but not everyone would read it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a great idea.  Someone asked if the questions could be merged here, but the SO staff said that's not recommended for a beta.

From what I can tell, the questions are exactly the same type of questions as what we see here.  That site's existence could kill this one, unless we get more people active here.

Can someone with some experience on AskAboutProjects email them and see how they feel about dwindling their site down?  I'm a n00b there, so I'm sure they wouldn't appreciate someone with a score of 1 asking them to stop what they're doing.

I've created a Facebook page and have encouraged others to join it and share it with their network.  I've also emailed a few colleagues, but so far I've had no luck getting any followers :(

Comment: Since PM@SE site is a continuation of AskAboutProjects and the proposal was submitted by AAP admins I don't think we have to convince anyone to transit traffic here - my question was more about letting people know about this site. I wouldn't close the old site down either, at least not until we're out of beta here.

Comment: @pawel - I'm not 100% up to speed on the purpose of the old site.  Thanks for clarifying.  I'm planning to spend this weekend doing some blogging about this site.  There are some project management blogs that take article submissions from outside bloggers that I've looked at.  In fact, I see that you and Mark Phillips are leaders in the community when it comes to speaking and writing about project management.  Perhaps you could write an article about this site in eweek.com or cnet.com or one of the news sources you're approved for.